# Build failure trying to create an Android App with Maven

Tags: android, maven, project, maven-3

I am trying to create an Android app using Maven as describe in [this blog](http://blog.akquinet.de/2011/01/14/starting-android-application-development-with-apache-maven/#WT)

I tried the command below on my Windows command prompt but got a  "Build Failure", Why?

```
C:\Users\abc\Desktop>mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-qui
ckstart \ -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes \ -DarchetypeVersion
=1.0.8 \ -DgroupId=com.yourcompany \ -DartifactId=yourandroidapp
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.143s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 12 05:58:36 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (C:\Users\abc\Desktop). Please verify you invoked Maven fr
om the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProject
Exception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash \ means line break in Linux shell command, just remove them if you are running on Windows:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-quickstart -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.8 -DgroupId=com.yourcompany -DartifactId=yourandroidapp
```

You will be ready to go.